# How to get the text value of the selected option of a select jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

if I'm passing a jquery object that I know is a select object, how can I get the text (not the value) of the option that is selected?

I'm needing something like this.

```
...function ($select){

    var selectedText = $select.selected().text();

}
```

And since $select is already a jquery object, I cant really change the selector of the object to use ":selected".

Comment: I believe `.text()` should work.  Post your code on JSFIDDLE, please.

Comment: You can query within the object to find children elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$select.find(':selected').text();
```

[should](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:-

```
Suppose you have a dropdown like this:-

    <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="aa">a</option>
        <option value="bb">b</option>
        <option value="cc">c</option>
    </select>
```

then javascript will be like this:-

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        obj = $('#dropdown :selected')
        value = obj.val()
        alert(value) # will alert aa/bb/cc 

        text = obj.text()
        alert(text) # will alert a/b/c
})
```